# How should I understand the .transform method in python-sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

## Introduction

I am following a tutorial, and I'm fairly new to Python, as well as Machine Learning.  (So, apologies if I seem like a noobie... it's because I am).  The tutorial can be found here: [Data Science Python Tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/data_science_python/)

### Lines of Code in Question

I see that a `bow_transformer` variable has been created early on:

```
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas).fit(messages['message'])
```

My understanding of 'Vectorizing' isn't really clear here... are we saying that each word per SMS message in the corpus get's it's own row?

Then, this variable is transformed (I assume `transform` here is to create some sort of (x,y) representation of a word so that a machine can read + count their occurrences.:

```
bow4 = bow_transformer.transform(messages['message'])
messages_bow = bow_transformer.transform(messages['message'])
```

Up to this point, I'm generally confused... and I think I've rationalized everything right in my head (correct me if I've made some logical errors above, which will help aid my understanding of Machine Learning + Python **tremendously.**

### Now, the main Question

My confusion was magnified by the following block:

```
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)
tfidf4 = tfidf_transformer.transform(bow4)
```

### My Interpretation

`messages_bow` is bow transformed (whatever that means), and then `messages_bow` is then fitted onto the `tfidfTransformer`, and this is assigned the `tfidf_transformer` variable.  This newly created `tfidf_transformer` variable is now doesn't look like a variable anymore, because the next line is creating a new variable (`tfidf4`) using the aforementioned procedure/object?

## Conclusion

I hope you guys can understand my confusion- I didn't know how to search for my question, because I simply don't know what I don't know.  My question is screaming "Noobie" and I hope this doesn't deter anyone from taking my question seriously.

Comment: You might find this [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiKMIuYidY0&list=PL5-da3qGB5ICeMbQuqbbCOQWcS6OYBr5A&index=10] quite useful.  It was clearer than a couple of courses I took from well known universities. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Vectorizers transform the corpus (for example text documents), into vectors [Vector Space Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model). There are many ways to do this, and the result will depend on the technique that is used. Vectorizers are necessary because models work with numbers, not with words.
In particular, the implementation of CountVectorizer will generate an array with the number of occurrences of each word. In this particular case CountVectorizer is used as a prior step to generate a TF-IDF (Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency) representation, which is one of the most popular techniques for determining the "importance" of a word in a document. The assumption of this model is that the terms that appear more are more likely to represent that document (Term frequency), however, 'common words' between the whole corpus should not be taken into account (Inverse Document Frequency), for example, connectors. This technique is widely used in the information retreival field.

Once you have the corpus in a vector space representation you can start to use this representation as an input for your machine learning technique.

The transform method, in particular, will return the result of applying the trained (fit) model to the element that is passed as argument. In other words, transformations 'translate' the input into the 'model representation language'.

Let's clarify this with an example:

Assume we have 3 documents (the content does not make sense, I know):

- Document 1: this is document one is grumpy.
- Document 2: this is document two is sad.
- Document 3: this is document three is happy.

CountVectorizer will learn the vocabulary when fit() is invoked.

`[this, is, document, one, grumpy, two, sad, three, happy]`

On the other side, when transform is invoked on the corpus, it will use the vocabulary to generate this matrix:

`[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(1) [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`

Which contains word ocurrences for each document. Here, the value 2 corresponds to the word 'is' which is repeated twice in each document. Also, the value '0' means that the word is not present in the document.

Now, we can use this matrix to train the TF-IDF model with fit() and it will generate the following vector:

`(2) [3, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Which contains the global occurrences of each word. Then, when you apply transform to (1), the tf-idf model will employ the vector generated in the fit phase (2) to create the tf-idf matrix:

`[0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`

in which lower numbers represent more common words. Pay attention that 'unique' words have higher numbers. This later matrix is the one you will use to train your ML model.

To summarize, if for example you want to use a clustering technique (KMeans for example) for classifying a bunch of documents the process would be:

1. Transform the documents to generate a VSM representation. Fit a TF-IDF model that will serve the propose of identifying which terms are most important in each document.
2. Fit the KMeans model which will generate clusters that  ideally will contain related documents. For this, the model will use the result generated in the last step to establish document relationship by identifying shared words between them.

All this explanation is in the context of natural language processing, if you want to use ML for identifying images of course you won't use tf-idf.

I hope I it helps!.

Comment: Absolutely great answer... But I have some more beginner questions. 1. You said that [the "transform" method will return the result of applying the trained (fit) model to the element that is passed as argument.] So here both Dictvectorizer and TF-IDF are models? 2. You said [This later matrix is the one you will use to train your ML model], but that matrix is itself generated using TF-IDF; So you mean the output of a model can be used inside another model? Why? Sorry I already understood what I needed from the answer, but these still sound confusing.